# Doughnut Chart in Card

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, syncfusion

I'm trying to implement an UI for my project and got stuck while using syncfusion circular chart type. I want to create a circular chart in a card widget. But I'm getting exceptions related to boundaries and I couldn't figured it out.
Here is what I'm trying to create:

[image]

And here is my error output:
[image]

Edit: Here is my code sample:

```
Card(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
          side: BorderSide(color: Colors.blueGrey, width: 0.5),
        ),
        child: Expanded(
          child: Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .65,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .80,
            child: Column(
              //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text(
                    "Genel Durum",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      letterSpacing: 0.3,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Divider(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  thickness: 0.3,
                  endIndent: 10,
                  indent: 10,
                ),
                _buildChart(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),

Widget _buildChart() {
    return Container(
      child: SfCircularChart(series: <CircularSeries>[
        DoughnutSeries<ChartData, String>(
            dataSource: chartData,
            pointColorMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.color,
            xValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.name,
            yValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.age,
            // Radius of doughnut
            radius: '10%')
      ]),
    );
  }
```

Thanks for your all help!

Comment: remove the `Expanded` from container you can't use `expanded` like that @Taha Ateş

Comment: ok I removed, can u figure out what is the problem here and how can I overcome it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**An Expanded widget must be a descendant or parent**

Crash the app or show blank white screen etc

**This crashes because Expanded is not a parent of a widget**

```
Container(
  child: Expanded(
    child: MyWidget(),
  ),
)
```

**Row**

```
Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: MyWidget(),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child:Text("Text Widget"),
    ),
  ],
)
```

**in Column**

```
Column(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: MyWidget(),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child:Text("Text Widget"),
    ),
  ],
),
```

checkout official flutter [Expanded Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html)

Also checkout following blogs.very good for flutter

[Flutter Layouts Walkthrough: Row, Column, Stack, Expanded, Padding](https://medium.com/coding-with-flutter/flutter-layouts-walkthrough-row-column-stack-expanded-padding-5ed64e8f9584)
it's very good tutorial easily explained by Andrea Bizzotto

[Resocode](https://resocoder.com)

[FilledStack](https://www.filledstacks.com)

[Github link for flutter tutorial](https://github.com/iampawan/FlutterExampleApps)

Comment: Thank you very much! I admit I'm still learning flutter trees but your answer make everything easier.

Comment: We all make mistakes while learning or doing something that all and also just helping manh nothing much,i have leaned something, i am just sharing it,that why we are here in StackoverFlow @TahaAteş

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `Expanded` and using the code below

```html
Card(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
          side: BorderSide(color: Colors.blueGrey, width: 0.5),
        ),
          child: Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .65,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .80,
            child: Column(
              //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text(
                    "Genel Durum",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      letterSpacing: 0.3,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Divider(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  thickness: 0.3,
                  endIndent: 10,
                  indent: 10,
                ),
                _buildChart(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
      ),

Widget _buildChart() {
    return Container(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .65,
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .80,
      child: SfCircularChart(series: <CircularSeries>[
        DoughnutSeries<ChartData, String>(
            dataSource: chartData,
            pointColorMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.color,
            xValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.name,
            yValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.age,
            // Radius of doughnut
            radius: '10%')
      ]),
    );
  }
```

Comment: already tried thanks to answer previously, didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the reported issue, you can wrap our chart widget with the **Expanded** widget as a parent else wrap the chart widget with **Container** and specify the size (height and width) to the same. The modified code can be found below,

```
    Card(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
        side: BorderSide(color: Colors.blueGrey, width: 0.5),
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .65,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .80,
          child: Column(
            //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(
                  "Genel Durum",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    letterSpacing: 0.3,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Divider(
                color: Colors.grey,
                thickness: 0.3,
                endIndent: 10,
                indent: 10,
              ),
              _buildChart(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
Widget _buildChart() {
  //Here we have wrapped our chart with Expanded widget
  return Expanded(
    child: SfCircularChart(series: <CircularSeries>[
      DoughnutSeries<ChartData, String>(
          dataSource: [
            ChartData(Colors.greenAccent, 'hi', 100),
            ChartData(Colors.blueAccent, 'to', 100)
          ],
          pointColorMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.color,
          xValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.name,
          yValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.age,
          // Radius of doughnut
          radius: '30%')
    ]),
  );
}
```